# Deployer Worker sometimes unable to load module

Tags: web8.5, deployer

On our CD environments we have a Deployer and a Deployer Worker Service all running on Windows Server 2012 R2. We are running Web 8.5 with latest Hotfixes.

When restarting the Deployer Worker Windows service, it sometimes fails to startup with an exception:

```
2018-06-11 10:07:16,951 ERROR ModuleFactory - Unable to create module
com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to load Module
    at com.tridion.deployer.ModuleFactory.createModule(ModuleFactory.java:115)
    at com.tridion.deployer.ModuleFactory.createModuleOnPreference(ModuleFactory.java:72)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionDeployerStepAdapter.configure(TridionDeployerStepAdapter.java:59)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory.processConfiguration(TridionExecutableStepFactory.java:169)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory.create(TridionExecutableStepFactory.java:140)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.step.BasicExecutableStepFactoryManager.getStep(BasicExecutableStepFactoryManager.java:44)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$execute(StepActor.scala:53)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:44)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:27)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: com.tridion.util.TridionReflectionException: Unable to load request class, was not found on classpath
    at com.tridion.util.ReflectionUtil.loadClassInstanceWithTypes(ReflectionUtil.java:65)
    at com.tridion.deployer.ModuleFactory.createModule(ModuleFactory.java:109)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.tridion.util.ReflectionUtil.loadClassInstanceWithTypes(ReflectionUtil.java:59)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

This particular behavior happens ~ 0-1 time out of 5 restarts causing all deployments to fail. Usually the service starts normal without errors and is also working like expected. This cant be reproduces 100% as it appears random.

Did anyone have the same problem already and knows a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is synchronization issue and has been fixed in last UDP 11.0+ releases