# SDL Web 8.5 Publishing Fails at Deploying stage

Tags: web8, publishing

We are using SDL web 8.5 and while publishing any item it was failing at deploying stage. After clearing old transaction and zip files from deployer server and restarting deployer service the issue gets resolved but we are still not able to find why this issue occurs. Error message in the log file is below

```
 ERROR ModuleFactory - Unable to create module
com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to load Module
    at com.tridion.deployer.ModuleFactory.createModule(ModuleFactory.java:115)
    at com.tridion.deployer.ModuleFactory.createModuleOnPreference(ModuleFactory.java:72)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionDeployerStepAdapter.configure(TridionDeployerStepAdapter.java:59)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory.processConfiguration(TridionExecutableStepFactory.java:169)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory.create(TridionExecutableStepFactory.java:140)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.step.BasicExecutableStepFactoryManager.getStep(BasicExecutableStepFactoryManager.java:44)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.execute(StepActor.scala:66)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$processStep(StepActor.scala:57)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:40)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:26)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.tridion.util.TridionReflectionException: Unable to load request class, was not found on classpath
    at com.tridion.util.ReflectionUtil.loadClassInstanceWithTypes(ReflectionUtil.java:65)
    at com.tridion.deployer.ModuleFactory.createModule(ModuleFactory.java:109)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.tridion.util.ReflectionUtil.loadClassInstanceWithTypes(ReflectionUtil.java:59)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

**Another issue in deployer config worker cleanup property is set to True but still deployer is not able to clean processed zip files we have to clean up this manually.**

Comment: This looks the same an error as reported in here https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18956/deployer-worker-sometimes-unable-to-load-module

Comment: Does deployer has permitions to delete files from file system?

Comment: @MarkoMilic yes it has delete permission deployer most of the time clear the files but some time it get failed but there is no error in log file when it failed to clear the zip package

Comment: @Velmurugan yes same issue but still there is no answer